# Как должны записываться [йэ] и [ййэ] после гласного?

Tags: орфография, фонология

В слове [маййэ] корень [майй] и окончание [э]. (Как в слове [бат'э] корень [бат'] и окончание [э]). Слово [маййэ] записывается как "Майе". Следовательно, [ййэ] после гласного записывается "йе".

Tom Sawyer, в английской Википедии дана транскрипция /ˈsɔːjər/, в русском, вроде бы, должно произноситься как [том сойэр], по логике "одинарное [j] в языке-источнике должно переходить в одинарное [j] при заимствовании слова в русский язык". Слово [сойэр] записывается как "Сойер". Следовательно, [йэ] после гласного записывается "йе".

Итак, и [ййэ], и [йэ] после гласного записываются как "йе"! Так не должно быть!

Как же решить эту проблему?

Попробую подумать о вариантах:

Если [йэ] записывать как "е" ("Том Соер"), тогда как записывать [ййэ]? Его можно было бы записывать "йе" ("Майе"), "йье" ("Майье"), "ййэ" ("Маййэ"), "ййе" ("Маййе").

Если [йэ] записывать как "йэ" ("Том Сойэр"), тогда как записывать [ййэ]? Его можно было бы записывать "йе" ("Майе"),"йье" ("Майье"),  "ййэ" ("Маййэ"), "ййе" ("Маййе").

Если [йэ] записывать как "йе" ("Том Сойер"), тогда как записывать [ййэ]? Его можно было бы записывать "йье" ("Майье"), "ййэ" ("Маййэ"), "ййе" ("Маййе").

Какой способ более правильный с точки зрения логики кириллической письменности, её истории?

Каким образом возникла данная проблема? Я, зная только современную кириллицу, предполагаю что примерно так:

1. Появилась идея сделать пары букв а-я, у-ю, э-е, о-ё.
2. Оказалось, что в русском языке [мэр] и [м'эр] звучат очень похоже. Тут в обоих из этих слов я подразумеваю гласную как в слове "мер". Попробуйте с этой гласной сказать это слово с твёрдым м ([м]) и с мягким м ([м']) - и увидите, что они очень похожи. При этом, согласная до неё звучит немного мягкой, поэтому решили всегда писать "е" после согласных. Поэтому, в исконно русских словах всегда "е" после согласной. Также оказалось, что в словах с "е" после согласной буквы, буква "е" не сильно смягчает предыдущую согласную, и не добавляет очень краткой [й] после неё, в отличие от букв "я" против "а", "ю" против "у".
3. Поэтому, буква "е" стала восприниматься на одном ряду с обычными гласными "а", "у", "о", с той лишь разницей, что в начале слова "е" означает [йэ] (тут тоже [э] как в слове "мер", например, слово "ель"), что осталось с той идеи, что "е" это такая же пара для "э", как "я" для "а", "ю" для "у".
4. Заимствовавлись слова "мер" (мэр) и "пер" (пэр) из иностранных языков, причём люди произносили букву е не как в обычных русских словах, а ближе к "а". То есть, в русском языке появился новый гласный, у которого до сих пор нет своего обозначения в фонетической транскрипции. Решили показать этот звук при помощи буквы "э", который был свободен в позициях после согласной (см. пункт 2).
5. При заимствовании слов из иностранных языков решили показывать звук [й] отдельной буквой "й". Поэтому "Сойер", а не "Соер". А почему е после й? Потому что "е" ведь после согласных означает гласный звук [э], как в слове "мер" (см. пункт 3). Про то, что буквы я, ю после "й" удваивают данный "й", и "е" вроде бы является такой же парой для э, и должна бы так же удваивать "й" на данном этапе, наверно, как бы забыли, или сочли что уже ушли от этого.
6. А в слове "Майе", по аналогии "бате", окончание [э] написали буквой "е", то есть, так же заменили "я" на "е". А {то, что после замены "я" на "е" после буквы "й", "е" уже не ведёт себя как буквы "я", "ю" - не удваивает предыдущий [й], и таким образом, один нужный [й] теряется}, наверно не заметили.

Comment: В кириллической транскрипции не принято использовать подряд два одинакового символа для обозначения долготы звука; более того, практически все заимствования, где в языке-источнике есть либо долгий согласный, либо долгий гласный, теряют долготу в русском, ср.: Ри[м]а (Римма), п[а]с (англ. _pass_ /pɑːs/). В слове _Майе_тоже нет [j:].

Comment: @Aer, я не о фонетике, а о фонологии, но, нужно было наверно в самом тексте подчеркнуть, а пока только тег. думаю, в фонологии должны использоваться двойные согласные, потому что это важно логически, например, в слове поддать буквы "д" в разных морфемах.

Comment: Разницы нет: фонологическая кириллическая транскрипция тоже кириллическая транскрипция, где долгота фонемы передается либо знаком __:__, либо макроном /◌̄/. Другое дело, если вы хотите обозначить две идущих рядом фонемы — тогда да, буква дублируется; но при фонологической записи используются либо косые черточки //, либо кавычки <>. Вот вам пример фонологической транскрипции: поддать /поддат'/, подать /подат'/, вожжи /вож':и/.

Comment: @Aer "В слове _Майе_тоже нет [j:]." - а в слове "майя" он есть, по этой вашей теории? если есть, то, и в "майе" должен быть, потому что корень не должен меняться. или там считается что [j:] чередуется с [j]? а если и в "майя" нету, тогда нормально...

Comment: @Aer с теорией о том что в словах майе и майя одинарная, обычная [й] можно легко и успешно поспорить, с привлечением доказательств в виде записей того, как люди реально говорят. https://tt.forvo.com/word/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F/ - во всех трех примерах двойной й. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkJ21e3Qt5c - двойной й.

Comment: это не моя теория. Фонетическая транскрипция описывает звучащую речь, а это в большинстве случаев вполне очевидная однозначная вещь. Примеры произношения слов из других языков приводить не стоит, а в ютубовском видео мне до конца не слышно, что там с йотом, — надо проверять на аппаратуре.

Comment: @Aer ой, там просто интерфейс татарский оказался, уберите tt. из адреса. я имел ввиду, представленной вами теории, теории, которая сейчас в ваших устах.

Comment: послушайте, я не описываю никакую фонетическую теорию; фонет. транскрипция — объективная вещь, она чаще всего не допускает интерпретаций (я не говорю про то, что, например, в школе или в большинстве вузов фонетика преподается на низком уровне и не учитывает достижения современной науки; это недопреподавание не является «теорией»).

Comment: @Aer в ваших примерах /поддат'/ но вожжи /вож':и/. то есть, у вас идёт фонетическое описание морфем. я же думал о другом: фонетическое описание отдельных фонологических фонем. это просто как бы тот же алфавит, но с более стройной системой записи, как бы один звук - одна буква, без этих яюеьъ. и по моей этой теории вож':и понимаются как вожжи, а длинных согласных в этой системе нет, так как длинная согласная в русском языке это то же самое что и двойная согласная.

Comment: повторю еще раз: есть фонетика (учение о звучащей речи) и фонология (ученик об абстрактных единицах — фонемах). [звук] — фонетика, /фонема/ — фонология. Понятно?.. Вот в фонологии есть разные фонологические теории, и, в частности, одни исследовали включают в систему фонем русского языка долгие согласные, другие — нет. Сформулируйте свою мысль четче, сделайте ее структурированной и постройте логическую цепочку. Иначе трудно понять, в чем суть вашего вопроса.

Comment: я задавал вопросы по этой проблеме в https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/17725 , https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4914507.html .

Answer (score -1):

тут внизу это не советы для подготовки к экзаменам. на экзаменах нужно писать как в словарях. это предложения для изменения норм русского языка...

---

идея о том, что в йя, йю, йе должна быть двойная й - нелогичная, потому что буквы я, ю, е после согласных не превращаются в версию с полноценной начальной й, как в начале слова, а й - это согласная. правописание [йя] нужно менять. вместо майя нужно писать либо майья, либо маййа, либо майъя. ну, есть такое правило, что разделительное ъ - только после приставок, поэтому, майъя отменяется. вариант маййа - странен для русского языка, так как обычно вместо йа пишут я. остаётся первый вариант - **майья, для [маййа]**.

пара букв э и е, оказывается, в отличие от пар а-я, у-ю, возникла не сразу. я прочитал в википедии в статье о букве э... оказывается, э был добавлен позже. сначала буква е была такой странной беспарной буквой, которая в начале слова и после гласных вела себя как я и ю, а после согласных вела себя как а и у. э была введена в русский язык с 3-мя целями: 1. для обозначения звуков типа æ в иностранных словах. 2. для обозначения обычного русского гласного звука как в букве е в начале слова. 3. для обозначения æ либо обычного русского гласного звука как в букве е после гласных, без й между ними.

буква э после согласных означает не гласную как в букве е, а гласную типа æ. поэтому, вариант написания маййэ отпадает.

писать йе либо ййе **для обозначения [ййэ]** также неправильно, как и йя, ййа для [ййа]. (смотрите 1-й абзац). нужно писать **йье**.

---

а **единичный й**, кстати, как должен записыватья? буду использовать слово сойер для иллюстрации, но это относится и к другим случаям. [сойэр] писать соер, сойер или сойэр?

сойэр отпадает, так как э после согласных обычно означает гласную æ. соер и сойер, по идее, технологии, означают одно и то же.

у варианта сойер есть 2 недостатка:

1. она длиннее, причём она возникла из чьего-то непонятного мне желания передавать й иностранных слов отдельной й в русском языке. то есть, она безосновательно, неоправданно длиннее.
2. она ещё норовит означать [соййэр]. в случае с йя удачно стала это означать: люди говорят секвоййа, маййа, вероятно, из-за этого. хотя в иностранных языках там одинарный й... то есть, сочетания йя, йе, йю - несколько двусмысленные, норовят быть понятыми по-разному.

и кроме того, вообще, йе странен для русского языка как и йа, как я написал в 1-м абзаце.

итак, сойер нужно отменить.

остается соер. нужно писать **соер**. также и с другими словами, в которых удваивание й ещё не стало нормой: **конвеер** вместо конвейер, **гуаява** вместо гуайява.

---

некоторые слова, например, папайя, паранойя, разные люди произносят по-разному. что с ними делать? тут надо решать, либо рекомендовать **одинарный й и писать папая, параноя**, **либо** рекомендовать **двойной й и писать папайья, паранойья**.